# Please help with context on this math equation for a Python application

Tags: python

I'm not requesting a solution... I simply do not understand what this instructor is requesting with this assignment.

"Light travels at 3 * 108 meters per second. A light-year is the distance a light beam travels in one year. Write a
program that calculates and displays the distance of a user-entered light-year."

It clearly states that a light year is a unit of distance, yet the instructor wants me to write a program in Python3 that calculates the distance of a user-entered light year??? I don't understand if the calculated distance of a LY is to be converted>displayed in LY, Statute Miles, Nautical Miles, Kilometers, Parsecs... etc.

It seems incomplete to me and I have received nothing from the instructor when asked for clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess it is intended to be "a user-entered number of light-years."  You are then supposed to take in a number of light years and convert that distance to some other unit.  As the other unit is not specified, I would use the SI unit of meters.

Comment: My first thought as well was to write a code for conversion from user-entered LY to an output in Kilometers to keep everything metric but for some reason that just doesn't (pardon the pun) compute in my brain for writing code.

Comment: Once you choose your output unit, you just need to multiply by the conversion factor, which you can precompute and hard code.  Meters are metric, too.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Ross; I'll work my way through it. I just needed someone else to look at it to reassure myself that I wasn't crazy...